# Unexpected downward movement of textarea text after going full-screen

Tags: javascript

I have a `textarea` to get user input. I want the input text to adjust its size based on the `textarea`'s width. by each `keydown` the input text resizes so that it can fit in the `textarea` (When the user types long texts the input text gets smaller to fit inside the `textarea`).

The code works as expected, except for one wired issue:

when I try to go fullscreen or vise versa I initiate this function and the text resizes as expected:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].onresize = function() {

       console.log('Window Resized..');
       setTimeout(function(){
       adjustTextSize();
       },1000);

}
```

But when you start typing and press any key at this point (after going fullscreen) the whole text moves downward about 20 pixels?!

The same thing happens again if you exit full screen when you exit full screen the same `onresize` function does the job and as expected we have the resized text, (after exiting fullscreen) press any key and the text moves downward again?!

Here is the code:

```
let textarea = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0];
textarea.focus();
textarea.style.overflow = "hidden"; 

$('textarea').keydown(function(){
   adjustTextSize();
});

document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].onresize = function() {

       console.log('Window Resized..');
       setTimeout(function(){
       adjustTextSize();
       },1000);

}

function adjustTextSize(){
    let font_size = 44;
    let textWidth = getTextWidth($('textarea').val(), `bold ${font_size}px Open Sans`).toFixed(2);
    let textareaWidth = $('textarea').width();
    console.log(textareaWidth, textWidth);

    while (textWidth > textareaWidth) {
           font_size -= 1;
           textWidth = getTextWidth($('textarea').val(), `bold ${font_size}px Open Sans`).toFixed(2);  
           console.log('inside while loop');             
    }
    $('textarea').css('font-size', font_size);
}


function getTextWidth(text, font) {
    var canvas = getTextWidth.canvas || (getTextWidth.canvas = document.createElement("canvas"));
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.font = font;
    var metrics = context.measureText(text);
    return metrics.width;
}
```